# Cannot write on partition while installing arch linux

Tags: linux, installation, arch-linux

I'm trying to install arch linux on a drive that hat fedora on it, yet. Fedora should be erased and I just started the installation process of the arch linux live USB. After partitoning the drive...

```
Device     Boot   [...] Size     Id Type
/dev/sda1   *           228,9G   83 Linux
/dev/sda2               4G       82 Linux Swap / Solaris
```

formatting /dev/sda1 was no problem. But making a swap-partition throws an error:

```
# mkswap /dev/sda2
mkswap: cannot open /dev/sda2: Device or recource is busy

# lsblk -l
[...]
sda
|-sda1                             ext4
|-sda2
   |-fedora_localhost--live-swap   swap
   |-fedora_localhost--live-home   ext4
   |-fedora_localhost--live-root   ext4
sdb
 |- [...]
```

I don't know how to continue the installation.

Any help is appreciated.

-- edit:    "|-fedora_localhost--live-root   swap" is "ext4"

Comment: Looks like your swap partition used to be an LVM partition...? Reboot.

Comment: Thank you @DanielB! I'll try it and tell then if that works.